# How to Return Multiple Match Values in Excel Using INDEX-MATCH and the to sum them up

Tags: excel, indexing, sum, match

i have an issue with excel using the INDEX MATCH formula.

I need to use 4 matching criteria on a 3.1k line database. I figured how to use add all the criteria, but it only returns the first line that is matching all the requirements.

How can I return all the lines that are matching my criteria. And the how can I sum them up.

This is the formula :

```
=INDEX($Z$2:$Z$3079,MATCH($AH$32&$AH$29&$AH$31&$AH$30,$U$2:$U$3079&$AE$2:$AE$3079&$AD$2:$AD$3079&$AC$2:$AC$3079,0))
```

I need to use this in order to populate a table.

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMIFS() to sum all that match.

```
=SUMIFS(Z:Z,U:U,AH32,AE:AE,AH29,AD:AD,AH31,AC:AC,AH30)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That really helps. But is there any way to do it with INDEX MATCH ?

Comment: No. That is only designed to return the first match only